# Prevent sleep for RDP client

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, sleep

I am using 2 Windows machines, where I am connecting from one of them (client, Win11) to another (host, Win10) using RDP (mstsc). My client PC has settings for display to be turned off and PC to be put to sleep after sometime (3 and 10 minutes respectively). On host PC I sometimes have stuff that may run for 5+ minutes, and when that stuff is running I sometimes leave the RDP in fullscreen and go do something else not involving client PC or maybe I just stare on the screen for 5 minutes, if I want to.

Sounds pretty normal setup to me, but my problem is that after 3 minutes pass, client PC turns off the display, and after 10 minutes it goes to sleep (which also loses RDP connection). I do not want that to happen when my RDP connection to the host is open. Or at least, when it is open and in fullscreen mode.

I searched quite a bit, but all articles I've been able to find are about keeping the **host** from sleeping, not about the **client**. Is there a way to do that? Essentially I want to treat RDP session as if it was a media player. You know, when you have a video playing in a media player, normally that prevents the display (and PC) from sleep. I want the same thing and without mouse-jigglers or the like, since I do not want to "synchronize" them with RDP session in any way.
Or to rephrase: prevent display and system from sleep when RDP is in focus, and prevent system only from sleep, if RDP is open, but not focused.

Interestingly, I think that in the past (WinXP times?) that was exactly the behavior, but not sure.

Comment: You will have to modify the host behavior, which I am guessing, has been configured by an Administrator so that won’t be possible

Comment: @Ramhound, how is host relevant here? As I explained in the question, I am asking about client PC, not about host.

Comment: @John I do not want to disable sleep on my client PC, I want RDP to prevent sleep, when it's active. Also I am admin on both PCs.

Comment: @john I already have set client PC to turn off the monitor after 3 minutes. I want it to not do that if I have RDP window open. I made an example of a media player in the original question: if you have media player open, but it's not playing a video file (sometimes music, too), PC will go to sleep, but as soon as you start a video - it will prevent PC from going to sleep in any capacity, including turning off monitor.

Comment: I think you can mostly ignore the factor of RDP. Your issue is with the client computer, and you want it to consider a specific application as superseding or negating the otherwise standard sleep settings. That is what your research needs to focus on. Because with RDP we generally consider SERVER-side issues (see the other's comments here proving this is common), you may consider re-writing your question to focus more specifically on the issue you are experiencing, and less on the surrounding factors.

Comment: I mistakenly typed host instead of client. The client is going to sleep, so the only thing you can do, is make the RDP connection prevent the client from going to sleep.  Once the client goes to sleep, the connection will be terminated, and there really isn't anything you can do about that.

Comment: Have you tried creating a "High Performance" power plan on the client pc?

Comment: @Ramhound, your advise basically comes down to "disable sleep". But that's not what I want.

Comment: @Mastaxx, power plan is completely irrelevant here. I assume your advise also will come down to disabling sleep, but that is not want I want. My original question provides an actual example of what behavior I want.

Comment: @Simbiat - You want the RDP connection to prevent your local system from going to sleep. Adjustments to your local system will be required to achieve that goal. Some problems don’t have solutions that are perfect

Comment: I can provide an autohotkey script that prevents the clientpc from going to sleep if Microsoft Remote Desktop is running.